# Using Roslyn for VS2015 Custom Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I'm building a Visual Studio 2015 custom editor (not a code editor extension, a totally custom WPF control) to edit .cs files. I'm really uncertain of what the right approach is to use the .NET Compilation SDK here.

So far I've tried:

- Getting the workspace->soltuion->projects and finding the open file using the file path that is passed to my editor factory. Of course if the document isn't part of the solution you get nothing.
- Parsing the raw source by pulling the data from the text buffer and spinning up my own isolated syntax tree.

None of what I'm doing now feels clean at all. Is there a more direct way to access compiler APIs for editor's document?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? You currently have access to a VS text buffer and you're trying to get the document for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be interpreting your question wrong but I'll take a shot. It sounds like you're trying to find the Roslyn document for a given text buffer.

There's actually a whole set of extension methods to make it easier to bridge the gap between Roslyn and Visual Studio objects.

See: [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.Extensions](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text/Extensions.cs)

They're not shipped with the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` NuGet Package though, you'll have to install them via:

`Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.Text -Version 1.0.0`

Given an `ITextSnapshot` or `ITextBuffer` these methods will allow you to map them back to the original Roslyn Documents (if any exist).

For more info: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/lrn-quick-tip-bridging-visual-studio-and-roslyn/

Comment: This sound like what I need, I'll update soon as I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @Paul: No; this isn't what you need.  If you're making a custom editor, you won't have a TextBuffer at all.  I assume that all you have is a HierachyItem or ProjectItem.

Comment: If one of the things he's tried is parsing text directly from a text buffer it sounds like he's got access to a TextBuffer or a snapshot of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

You *need* to use the existing stock Workspace, or you won't get references, nor, more importantly, preprocessor symbols (which affect the shape of the syntax tree).

Note that VS can have a couple of different Workspaces, including the main `VisualStudioWorkspace` for the current solution, `MiscellaneousFilesWorkspace` for other files, and some other debugger-related ones. ([full list](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs,9ea8f5c40adb7b8e,references))

Comment: Is this method, resolving the file by searching the workspace documents, the best way, or can I get the document ID directly somehow?

Comment: @Paul: You can try to figure out how Roslyn does this mapping when opening normal editors.  Look at http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/Implementation/AbstractEditorFactory.cs, although I'm not sure if that's the right place.

Comment: On further thought, look at http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/Implementation/ProjectSystem/DocumentProvider.cs,79 (although I'm not sure how much that will help)